# How to make java3d shows on the JSP page?

Tags: java, servlets, applet, java-3d

I'm new to Java-3D and Java applet and try to use servlet.

Please How to make java3d shows on the JSP page ?

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: *"Is there a better way to do it?"* Probably 'render an image on the server, send that to the client (the browser)'.  But the devil is in the details.

Comment: Thank Thompson. However, this approach may not achieve page interaction.

Comment: Note how I said *"the devil is in the details"*?  Your core question was *"How to make java3d **shows** on the JSP page ?"*  Interacting with the model is 'the details'.  Please try to fill out the specification more completely.

Comment: Applets and Servlets are two completely different things. Which is the one you are trying to use here?